# Shuffle an array in Arduino software

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I have a problem with Shuffling this array with Arduino software:

```
int questionNumberArray[10]={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
```

Does anyone know a build in function or a way to shuffle the values in the array without any repeating?

Comment: Did you try to google "shuffle array"?

Comment: http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=43424.0

Comment: I did, these answers work only for binary arrays, because values can be repeated as i tried to explain in my question.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way would be this little `for` loop:

```
int questionNumberArray[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

const size_t n = sizeof(questionNumberArray) / sizeof(questionNumberArray[0]);

for (size_t i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
{
    size_t j = random(0, n - i);

    int t = questionNumberArray[i];
    questionNumberArray[i] = questionNumberArray[j];
    questionNumberArray[j] = t;
}
```

Let's break it line by line, shall we?

```
int questionNumberArray[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
```

You don't need to put number of cells if you initialize an array like that. Just leave the brackets empty like I did.

```
const size_t n = sizeof(questionNumberArray) / sizeof(questionNumberArray[0]);
```

I decided to store number of cells in `n` constant. Operator `sizeof` gives you number of bytes taken by your array and number of bytes taken by one cell. You divide first number by the second and you have size of your array.

```
 for (size_t i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
```

Please note, that range of the loop is `n - 1`. We don't want `i` to ever have value of last index.

```
size_t j = random(0, n - i);
```

We declare variable `j` that points to some random cell with index greater than `i`. That is why we never wanted `i` to have `n - 1` value - because then `j` would be out of bound. We get random number with Arduino's `random` function: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Random

```
 int t = questionNumberArray[i];
 questionNumberArray[i] = questionNumberArray[j];
 questionNumberArray[j] = t;
```

Simple swap of two values. It's possible to do it without temporary `t` variable, but the code is less readable then.

In my case the result was as follows:

```
questionNumberArray[0] = 0
questionNumberArray[1] = 9
questionNumberArray[2] = 7
questionNumberArray[3] = 4
questionNumberArray[4] = 6
questionNumberArray[5] = 5
questionNumberArray[6] = 1
questionNumberArray[7] = 8
questionNumberArray[8] = 2
questionNumberArray[9] = 3
```